# how to get the original function back in lua

Tags: lua

suppose I write the following code:

```
>a=print
>print=1
>a=1

> print(1)
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'print' (a number value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

How can I get the original function "print"?

Comment: `print=function(...)io.write(table.concat({...},'\t')..'\n')end`

Comment: Technically you can use a work-around if you plan ahead. e.g. `_print = print; print = 1` then later you can set it back to normal `print = _print`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Lua functions are values, just like any other value. If you modify the value where a Lua function is stored, then the function won't be stored there anymore. And if you modify the last value that holds that function... then the function is lost forever.

From C, you might be able to invoke `luaopen_base` again, but that's only accessible from C.